# Passing pointer to generic structure

Tags: c#, c, interop, marshalling

I have to interface with a C function from C#
The function sends a message over the network.

Here is my working definition in C#:

```
delegate void SendNetMessageDelegate(uint messageCode, ref MessageData messageData, uint messageSize);
```

and the MessageData is defined like that:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MessageData { ... }
```

those definitions work good so far.

The problem is that sometimes I need to call the same function with another payload.
That means I would have to make another delegate that takes "OtherMessageData" struct instead of "MessageData"

So I would have to add another SendNetMessageDelegate that takes another struct as reference.

Is there an easier way?
So I can call SendNetMessage(messageCode, ref *AnyStructHere* messageData, messageSize)

I tried changing the parameter type to "object" and then casting my structs to object, but that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about generics

```
delegate void SendNetMessageDelegate<TPayload>(uint messageCode, ref TPayload payload, uint messageSize);
```

Comment: Then I would use the delegate like this: SendNetMessageDelegate<OtherMessageData> SendNetMessageThatTakesOtherMessageData = ...;
But that way I'd still have to make multiple definitions.
I'd like to have one function definition that takes all structs. Is that possible?